# Substring save all spaces in a string

Tags: java

I have a string  with multiple spaces and i want to use the substring method on this string and save all my spaces.

My string:

[my string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb2Ex.png)

when i use a.substring(16) i want to get

[what i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVOdX.png)

but i get

[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlVgu.png)

Substring replace all my spaces by one space.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post strings as text rather than images so that people can easily copy and test them. Normally, multiple spaces should not be collapsed into a single character. Is the whitespace in the string not a standard space character?

Comment: Is it really faster to take a screenshot, upload it to another website, copy/paste the link, and that 3 times, than to copy/paste 3 short lines?

Comment: `String.substring` can't merge space,you try again?

Comment: That  `i use a.substring(16)` doesn't mean anything. Post real code. (**as text**)

Comment: I tried at the beginning to put my chain in text but the editor of the site replaces my spaces by only one, suddenly it would be ambiguous, that's why I made screenshots. sorry guys...

Comment: For future reference: for fixed-format (spacing and linebreaks significant) computer input _and_ output, **use 'code' markdown** by indenting separate line(s) 4 spaces or separating with triple backticks, surrounding inline text (not containing backtick) with backticks, or the {} button or control+K shortcut. Click the ? button and one of the tabs, like 'Code', for more.

Answer (score 1):

`substring` treats spaces like any other character. Something else is deleting your spaces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str =" some    string    with some    spaces";

    System.out.println("\""+str.substring(9)+"\"");
}
```

output: `"string    with some    spaces"`

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: Thank you. So the problem isn't in my java project but in the other application to whome i send the file and get a response....

Comment: @sfox That's not what he said. He said it's not the substring method fault. But we don't know how you use it. Post some code in your question

Comment: @forpas I get what you're saying, and although my answers isn't what OP had in mind, it does answer the specific question he asked - how to preserve spaces when calling `.substring`. Since stack overflow is basically a community-driven Q&A wiki, I'd say this *is* an answer, just not to the underlying question. Hopefully, OP will re-post a more accurate question.

Comment: *Something else is deleting your spaces* is **not** an answer. This is why we all use the comments.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, it's not the substring method but a trim method used after. Thank you :) :)

Comment: I fail to see your point. The question was "how to preserve spaces" when using `substring`. The answer is "just use `substring`. It doesn't delete spaces. If there are missing spaces, it's not because of the `substring method`. Do you have a better answer to the specific question OP asked?

Comment: @Malt If I had an answer I would post it. You **did not have an answer** but a comment posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this before substring

```
    String str = "this    is a    string";
    while(str.contains("  ")) {
        str = str.replaceAll("  ", " ");
    }
```